# SetEvent state from golang to c (cgo)

Tags: go, events, dll, cgo

I wrote DLL to handle my VSCAN communication in golang. I'm facing a really hard problem now. Is there any way to signal state from cgo to c/cpp program?

I'm using a large CPP project, inside it calls external golang DLL (compiled with GCC). Program pass Handle to the event:

```
    // this is a function from DLL (written in go). I want to pass the event handler there.
    VSCAN_STATUS VSCAN_SetRcvEvent(VSCAN_HANDLE Handle, HANDLE Event);

    // Calling it from c:
    sg_hEventRecv = CreateEvent(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, nullptr);
    VSCAN_SetRcvEvent(1, sg_hEventRecv)
```

I store the passed HANDLER in go dll:

```
package test

import "C"

var event C.HANDLE
func signalState(){
C.SetEvent(event) 
}

//export VSCAN_SetRcvEvent
func VSCAN_SetRcvEvent(Handle VSCAN_HANDLE, Event C.HANDLE) int {
    event = Event
    return 0
}
```

Every time I want to signal state from go, it returns error code 6 (invalid handler).